# Is it possible to look up the key of a dictionary value under a certain number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value

For example, I have a dictionary like such:

```
sampleDict = {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

I know that I can use the `get()` function to get the value of a particular key, but is there a way to do the opposite in a conditional manner?

For example, what if I wanted to get the key for maximum number in `sampleDict`. Is there a good function or set of functions I can use to quickly and efficiently get that value? I've tried a quick Google search, but I'm not coming up with what I want. In this example, I would want to receive the number `1` since the value for key `1` is the maximum value in the dictionary.

Comment: I don't think there is a out of the box way to do that in less than O(n). Meaning, iterating over throughout the items in the dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get with max value you can use `max()` builtin function:

```py
sampleDict = {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}

max_key = max(sampleDict, key=sampleDict.get)
print(max_key)
```

Prints:

```
1
```

Comment: For me this is the most elegant solution so far. Didn't know this tricky 'key' parameter in the max func.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, it's useful to know it. Same for `min()`

Comment: Thank you @AndrejKesely! How would I extend this to get the key with the corresponding maximum value given a condition (e.g., the corresponding value must be < 3)?

Comment: @324 You can do `max_key = max((k for k, v in sampleDict.items() if v < 3), key=sampleDict.get)` or `max_key = max((v, k) for k, v in sampleDict.items() if v < 3)[1]` etc.

Comment: My problem with this method is that eventually the list will be empty since I am popping off values using `pop(max_key)`, so it throws and error. How can I separate the steps so that the max is only calculated IF the list comprehension list is not empty. Thank you so much for your help so far! I really appreciate it @AndrejKesely

Comment: @324 [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) has an `default=` argument, you can use it. Or you can check `if len(sampleDict) > 0: max_key = ...`

Answer (score 2):

This return a array of keys that have the value you search.

```
keys = [k for k, v in sampleDict.items() if v == value]
print(keys)
```

Comment: OP says " I would want to receive the number 1 since the value for key 1 is the maximum value in the dictionary."

Comment: How would I extend this to get the key with the corresponding maximum value?

Comment: just like @Andrej Kesely did it

Comment: My problem with that method is that eventually the list will be empty since I am popping off values using `pop(max_key)`, so it throws and error. How can I separate the steps so that the max is only calculated IF the list comprehension list is not empty. Thank you so much for your help so far @PaulDlc

Comment: well, an option is that you catch the max value appart only use "v" attribute that reference the value of the keys in the dictionary, and later use my code with v == max_value. Or, using the Andrej method, you can arround with [ ] for that return a array. Have both option

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop to find the key which matches the max value:

```
sampleDict = {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}

def foo(sampleDict):
    m = max(sampleDict.values())
    for k, v in sampleDict.items():
        if v == m:
            return k

print(foo(sampleDict))
```

**Result**: `1`

This obviously does not account for any dupe max values. It just finds the first value that matches the max.

In terms of performance, this assumes the input size is not massive.

If we needed to make it more efficient, we could calculate the maximum as we iterate.

Comment: Thank you! Performance in this is important to me, and I am having this inside of another for loop, so I want to avoid n^2